# Get Javascript value from an external file

Tags: javascript

The details of the locations `var locations` in the Javascript file. I want to integrate the details of these locations from the JS file outside.

```
....

function mainMap() {
        function locationData(locationURL, locationPrice, locationPriceDetails, locationImg, locationTitle, locationAddress) {
            return ('<a href="' + locationURL + '" class="listing-img-container"><div class="infoBox-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div class="listing-img-content"><span class="listing-price">' + locationPrice + '<i>' + locationPriceDetails + '</i></span></div><img src="' + locationImg + '" alt=""></a><div class="listing-content"><div class="listing-title"><h4><a href="#">' + locationTitle + '</a></h4><p>' + locationAddress + '</p></div></div>')
        }


var locations = [
[locationData('link1', '$275,000', '$520 / sq ft', 'img.jpg', 'Eagle Apartmets', "9364 School St. Lynchburg, NY"), 40.7427837, -73.11445617675781, 1, markerIcon], 
[locationData('link2', '$135,000', '$120 / sq ft', 'img.jpg', 'Stack Apartmets', "1234 School St. Lynchburg, NY"), 40.7317837, -73.11435617675781, 1, markerIcon],
,];


var mapZoomAttr = $('#map').attr('data-map-zoom');
        var mapScrollAttr = $('#map').attr('data-map-scroll');
        if (typeof mapZoomAttr !== typeof undefined && mapZoomAttr !== false) {
            var zoomLevel = parseInt(mapZoomAttr);
        } else {
            var zoomLevel = 5;
        }
....
```

## What have I done?

**PHP File:**

```
[...]
echo "<script>var locationDetails = [[locationData('link1','$275,000','$520 / sq ft', 'img.jpg', 'Eagle Apartmets', "9364 School St.Lynchburg, NY"), 40.7427837, -73.11445617675781, 1, markerIcon], [locationData('link2', '$135,000', '$120 / sq ft', 'img.jpg', 'StackApartmets', "1234 School St. Lynchburg, NY"), 40.7317837, -73.11435617675781,1, markerIcon],];
[...]
```

**JS File:**

```
var locations = locationDetails;
```

**Result:**

Not working.

Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

[The full version of the JS file](https://pastebin.com/SAJCQMn8)

Comment: I am not 100% clear on the question. So you have a .js file you want to load values & variables from? You need to `export const myVar = 'VARRR'` and `import { myVar } from './myfile'` before you can use `myVar`.

Comment: @Dan You understant right, cloud you show me sample on the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) & [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) at MDN.

Example for export:

```
export const one = 1

// or to export multiple
const two = 2
const three = 3

export {
  two,
  three
}
```

Example of import:

```
import { one, two, three } from './export' // path of export
console.log(one, two, three)
```